# Código bash que no se ejecuta correctamente

Tags: bash, script

Tengo el siguiente código bash el cual no llega a ejecutarse completamente:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Comprobar si el número total de argumentos es el correcto.

    if [ $# -lt 2 ]; 
      then
      echo "Argumentos erróneos."
      exit 1
    fi
    
    usuarios_fichero="$1"

# Comprobar si el fichero de usuarios existe

    if [ ! -f "$usuarios_fichero" ]; then
      echo "$usuarios_fichero no existe."
      exit 1
    fi

#Crear la carpeta de usuarios 

    usuarios_dir="C:\Users\4444m\OneDrive\Escritorio\Práctica Script"
    mkdir -p "$usuarios_dir"


# Leer los nombres de usuario del fichero y crear las carpetas correspondientes

    while IFS= read -r usuario; 
    do

#Crear carpeta del usuario
  

    usuario_dir="$usuarios_dir/$usuario"
      mkdir -p "$usuario_dir"

  # Copiar los archivos a las carpetas de usuarios
  

    for ((i = 2; i <= $#; i++)); do
        archivo="${!i}"
        cp "$archivo" "$usuario_dir"
        
      done
    done < "$usuarios_fichero"
    
    echo "Tarea completada."
```

El script recibe le nombre de un archivo como su primer parámetro, que son nombres de usuario.

Si el archivo existe, el script creará una carpeta para cada uno de los nombres de usuario. Estas carpetas se crearán en una ubicación específica en el sistema, que se asume que ya existe y se llama "/usuarios/".

El script también debe copiar los archivos que se le pasen como segundo, tercer, etc., parámetros.

Estos archivos se le pasan al script con su ruta completa, es decir, se proporciona la ubicación exacta del archivo

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: ¿Podría explicar qué debe hacer el código, no entendí cuál es su tarea?

Comment: ¿Estás usando WSL?

Comment: El script recibe le nombre de un archivo como su primer parámetro, que son nombres de usuario.
Si el archivo existe, el script creará una carpeta para cada uno de los nombres de usuario. Estas carpetas se crearán en una ubicación específica en el sistema, que se asume que ya existe y se llama "/usuarios/".
El script también debe copiar los archivos que se le pasen como segundo, tercer, etc., parámetros. Estos archivos se le pasan al script con su ruta completa, es decir, se proporciona la ubicación exacta del archivo.

Comment: Para ejecutar el script estoy usando MobaXTerm

Comment: "No se ejecuta bien" significa que sale algún error? No sale nada? Qué resultado sale en vez de lo que esperas? Mobaxterm conectado a algún servidor linux? Todo va EN la pregunta, que puedes [edit] todas las veces que haga falta. Los comentarios son para los que intentamos entender bien qué pasa antes de responderte. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que está ocurriendo con el código es que el *shell de Bash* está interpretando la barra invertida `\` como un carácter especial. En **Bash**, esta barra invertida se interpreta como una secuencia de escape.

Si esta ruta de archivo está realmente correcta:

```
usuarios_dir="C:\Users\4444m\OneDrive\Escritorio\Práctica Script"
```

Para evitar que la barra invertida sea interpretada por **bash**, debes usar un escape, `\\` .

**(** *También se debe usar* `\` *para espaciar con un espacio* `Práctica\ Script` **)**

También puedes usar comillas simples para que **Bash** no las interprete:

```
usuarios_dir='C:\Users\4444m\OneDrive\Escritorio\Práctica Script'
```

No se entendió además de no proporcionar el sistema operativo.

Al principio mencionaste el directorio (por defecto de **Windows**).

```
usuarios_dir="C:\Users\4444m\OneDrive\Escritorio\Práctica Script"
```

Al crear el directorio, se utilizó una barra invertida (estándar de **GNU/Linux**).

```
usuario_dir="$usuarios_dir/$usuario"
```